# How can I add value labels to only one line on a multi-line plot on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

The plot depicts two lines for time series of oil prices, and one for standard deviation of certain intervals.

Is it possible to have value labels attached only to the Standard Deviation line?

The code for the plot used:

```
ggplot(data.final, aes(x=Date, y=Value, colour=Type)) +
geom_line() +
xlab("Year") +
ylab("Price (2013 U.S. Dollars)")
```

And the data used is:

```
         Date      Value               Type

1   2014-09-30  96.990000     Montly Average
2   2014-08-31 101.850000     Montly Average
3   2014-07-31 105.710000     Montly Average
4   2014-06-30 108.010000     Montly Average
5   2014-05-31 105.510000     Montly Average
6   2014-04-30 104.780000     Montly Average
7   2014-03-31 104.150000     Montly Average
8   2014-02-28 104.940000     Montly Average
9   2014-01-31 104.190000     Montly Average
10  2013-12-31 107.940000     Montly Average
11  2013-11-30 105.850000     Montly Average
12  2013-10-31 106.390000     Montly Average
13  2013-09-30 108.400000     Montly Average
14  2013-08-31 106.660000     Montly Average
15  2013-07-31 103.360000     Montly Average
16  2013-06-30 100.330000     Montly Average
17  2013-05-31 100.300000     Montly Average
18  2013-04-30 101.660000     Montly Average
19  2013-03-31 105.480000     Montly Average
20  2013-02-28 111.220000     Montly Average
21  2013-01-31 107.540000     Montly Average
22  2012-12-31 105.670000     Montly Average
23  2012-11-30 107.100000     Montly Average
24  2012-10-31 108.680000     Montly Average
25  2012-09-30 110.960000     Montly Average
26  2012-08-31 108.390000     Montly Average
27  2012-07-31  99.220000     Montly Average
28  2012-06-30  94.240000     Montly Average
29  2012-05-31 107.450000     Montly Average
30  2012-04-30 117.380000     Montly Average
31  2012-03-31 122.280000     Montly Average
32  2012-02-29 116.150000     Montly Average
33  2012-01-31 109.540000     Montly Average
34  2011-12-31 106.210000     Montly Average
35  2011-11-30 108.520000     Montly Average
36  2011-10-31 103.880000     Montly Average
37  2011-09-30 106.000000     Montly Average
38  2011-08-31 104.960000     Montly Average
39  2011-07-31 109.980000     Montly Average
40  2011-06-30 107.520000     Montly Average
41  2011-05-31 108.840000     Montly Average
42  2011-04-30 115.760000     Montly Average
43  2011-03-31 108.580000     Montly Average
44  2011-02-28  99.870000     Montly Average
45  2011-01-31  92.190000     Montly Average
46  2010-12-31  89.180000     Montly Average
47  2010-11-30  83.740000     Montly Average
48  2010-10-31  80.340000     Montly Average
49  2010-09-30  75.290000     Montly Average
50  2010-08-31  74.350000     Montly Average
51  2010-07-31  72.650000     Montly Average
52  2010-06-30  73.980000     Montly Average
53  2010-05-31  76.620000     Montly Average
54  2010-04-30  82.980000     Montly Average
55  2010-03-31  77.370000     Montly Average
56  2010-02-28  73.550000     Montly Average
57  2010-01-31  76.640000     Montly Average
58  2009-12-31  75.490000     Montly Average
59  2009-11-30  77.630000     Montly Average
60  2009-10-31  73.280000     Montly Average
61  2009-09-30  67.910000     Montly Average
62  2009-08-31  71.320000     Montly Average
63  2009-07-31  64.970000     Montly Average
64  2009-06-30  69.210000     Montly Average
65  2009-05-31  57.400000     Montly Average
66  2009-04-30  50.180000     Montly Average
67  2009-03-31  45.580000     Montly Average
68  2009-02-28  43.140000     Montly Average
69  2009-01-31  44.970000     Montly Average
70  2008-12-31  41.000000     Montly Average
71  2008-11-30  51.380000     Montly Average
72  2008-10-31  68.620000     Montly Average
73  2008-09-30  95.970000     Montly Average
74  2008-08-31 113.210000     Montly Average
75  2008-07-31 131.220000     Montly Average
76  2008-06-30 127.590000     Montly Average
77  2008-05-31 118.950000     Montly Average
78  2008-04-30 103.470000     Montly Average
79  2008-03-31  96.780000     Montly Average
80  2008-02-29  89.960000     Montly Average
81  2008-01-31  87.170000     Montly Average
82  2007-12-31  85.750000     Montly Average
83  2007-11-30  86.730000     Montly Average
84  2007-10-31  77.140000     Montly Average
85  2007-09-30  73.250000     Montly Average
86  2007-08-31  67.210000     Montly Average
87  2007-07-31  69.460000     Montly Average
88  2007-06-30  65.760000     Montly Average
89  2007-05-31  64.540000     Montly Average
90  2007-04-30  63.840000     Montly Average
91  2007-03-31  59.050000     Montly Average
92  2007-02-28  55.680000     Montly Average
93  2007-01-31  52.010000     Montly Average
94  2006-12-31  58.670000     Montly Average
95  2006-11-30  56.820000     Montly Average
96  2006-10-31  56.500000     Montly Average
97  2006-09-30  59.770000     Montly Average
98  2006-08-31  68.780000     Montly Average
99  2006-07-31  69.050000     Montly Average
100 2006-06-30  65.080000     Montly Average
101 2006-05-31  64.910000     Montly Average
102 2006-04-30  64.060000     Montly Average
103 2006-03-31  57.650000     Montly Average
104 2006-02-28  57.580000     Montly Average
105 2006-01-31  58.310000     Montly Average
106 2005-12-31  53.130000     Montly Average
107 2005-11-30  51.310000     Montly Average
108 2005-10-31  53.670000     Montly Average
109 2005-09-30  56.540000     Montly Average
110 2005-08-31  56.630000     Montly Average
111 2005-07-31  52.850000     Montly Average
112 2005-06-30  50.980000     Montly Average
113 2005-05-31  45.000000     Montly Average
114 2005-04-30  47.100000     Montly Average
115 2005-03-31  45.580000     Montly Average
116 2005-02-28  39.820000     Montly Average
117 2005-01-31  37.810000     Montly Average
118 2004-12-31  34.260000     Montly Average
119 2004-11-30  34.880000     Montly Average
120 2004-10-31  37.580000     Montly Average
121 2004-09-30  35.480000     Montly Average
122 2004-08-31  38.300000     Montly Average
123 2004-07-31  34.480000     Montly Average
124 2004-06-30  33.410000     Montly Average
125 2004-05-31  34.470000     Montly Average
126 2004-04-30  31.070000     Montly Average
127 2004-03-31  30.460000     Montly Average
128 2004-02-29  28.400000     Montly Average
129 2004-01-31  28.680000     Montly Average
130 2003-12-31  27.860000     Montly Average
131 2003-11-30  27.500000     Montly Average
132 2003-10-31  27.130000     Montly Average
133 2003-09-30  25.270000     Montly Average
134 2003-08-31  27.620000     Montly Average
135 2003-07-31  26.630000     Montly Average
136 2003-06-30  25.470000     Montly Average
137 2003-05-31  24.250000     Montly Average
138 2003-04-30  23.380000     Montly Average
139 2003-03-31  27.420000     Montly Average
140 2003-02-28  30.200000     Montly Average
141 2003-01-31  28.070000     Montly Average
142 2002-12-31  25.710000     Montly Average
143 2002-11-30  23.320000     Montly Average
144 2002-10-31  26.180000     Montly Average
145 2002-09-30  26.830000     Montly Average
146 2002-08-31  25.320000     Montly Average
147 2002-07-31  24.570000     Montly Average
148 2002-06-30  23.830000     Montly Average
149 2002-05-31  24.590000     Montly Average
150 2002-04-30  24.410000     Montly Average
151 2002-03-31  22.850000     Montly Average
152 2002-02-28  18.910000     Montly Average
153 2002-01-31  18.290000     Montly Average
154 2001-12-31  17.640000     Montly Average
155 2001-11-30  17.530000     Montly Average
156 2001-10-31  19.540000     Montly Average
157 2001-09-30  23.960000     Montly Average
158 2001-08-31  24.310000     Montly Average
159 2001-07-31  23.430000     Montly Average
160 2001-06-30  25.610000     Montly Average
161 2001-05-31  25.580000     Montly Average
162 2001-04-30  24.060000     Montly Average
163 2001-03-31  23.430000     Montly Average
164 2001-02-28  24.740000     Montly Average
165 2001-01-31  22.690000     Montly Average
166 2000-12-31  22.160000     Montly Average
167 2000-11-30  30.100000     Montly Average
168 2000-10-31  30.220000     Montly Average
169 2000-09-30  29.740000     Montly Average
170 2000-08-31  27.050000     Montly Average
171 2000-07-31  26.010000     Montly Average
172 2000-06-30  27.320000     Montly Average
173 2000-05-31  25.510000     Montly Average
174 2000-04-30  22.030000     Montly Average
175 2000-03-31  25.080000     Montly Average
176 2000-02-29  24.620000     Montly Average
177 2000-01-31  23.180000     Montly Average
178 1999-12-31  23.530000     Montly Average
179 1999-11-30  23.060000     Montly Average
180 1999-10-31  21.500000     Montly Average
181 1999-09-30  21.480000     Montly Average
182 1999-08-31  19.290000     Montly Average
183 1999-07-31  17.660000     Montly Average
184 1999-06-30  15.400000     Montly Average
185 1999-05-31  15.380000     Montly Average
186 1999-04-30  14.810000     Montly Average
187 1999-03-31  12.080000     Montly Average
188 1999-02-28  10.050000     Montly Average
189 1999-01-31  10.670000     Montly Average
190 1998-12-31  10.120000     Montly Average
191 1998-11-30  11.760000     Montly Average
192 1998-10-31  12.810000     Montly Average
193 1998-09-30  13.070000     Montly Average
194 1998-08-31  12.180000     Montly Average
195 1998-07-31  12.000000     Montly Average
196 1998-06-30  11.680000     Montly Average
197 1998-05-31  12.630000     Montly Average
198 1998-04-30  11.470000     Montly Average
199 1998-03-31  11.530000     Montly Average
200 1998-02-28  12.430000     Montly Average
201 1998-01-31  13.400000     Montly Average
202 1997-12-31  16.310000     Montly Average
203 1997-11-30  18.380000     Montly Average
204 1997-10-31  19.060000     Montly Average
205 1997-09-30  17.950000     Montly Average
206 1997-08-31  17.770000     Montly Average
207 1997-07-31  17.290000     Montly Average
208 1997-06-30  17.340000     Montly Average
209 1997-05-31  18.450000     Montly Average
210 1997-04-30  16.770000     Montly Average
211 1997-03-31  18.070000     Montly Average
212 1997-02-28  18.590000     Montly Average
213 1997-01-31  21.240000     Montly Average
214 1996-12-31  21.640000     Montly Average
215 1996-11-30  20.870000     Montly Average
216 1996-10-31  21.720000     Montly Average
217 1996-09-30  20.350000     Montly Average
218 1996-08-31  18.680000     Montly Average
219 1996-07-31  17.790000     Montly Average
220 1996-06-30  17.000000     Montly Average
221 1996-05-31  16.990000     Montly Average
222 1996-04-30  17.770000     Montly Average
223 1996-03-31  17.090000     Montly Average
224 1996-02-29  15.990000     Montly Average
225 1996-01-31  16.550000     Montly Average
226 1995-12-31  16.810000     Montly Average
227 1995-11-30  15.560000     Montly Average
228 1995-10-31  14.990000     Montly Average
229 1995-09-30  15.430000     Montly Average
230 1995-08-31  15.380000     Montly Average
231 1995-07-31  15.020000     Montly Average
232 1995-06-30  16.240000     Montly Average
233 1995-05-31  17.240000     Montly Average
234 1995-04-30  17.650000     Montly Average
235 1995-03-31  16.490000     Montly Average
236 1995-02-28  16.640000     Montly Average
237 1995-01-31  16.080000     Montly Average
238 1994-12-31  15.340000     Montly Average
239 1994-11-30  16.230000     Montly Average
240 1994-10-31  15.300000     Montly Average
241 1994-09-30  15.080000     Montly Average
242 1994-08-31  15.730000     Montly Average
243 1994-07-31  16.840000     Montly Average
244 1994-06-30  15.880000     Montly Average
245 1994-05-31  15.150000     Montly Average
246 1994-04-30  13.900000     Montly Average
247 1994-03-31  12.530000     Montly Average
248 1994-02-28  12.730000     Montly Average
249 1994-01-31  13.270000     Montly Average
250 1993-12-31  12.030000     Montly Average
251 1993-11-30  13.490000     Montly Average
252 1993-10-31  14.590000     Montly Average
253 1993-09-30  13.900000     Montly Average
254 1993-08-31  14.570000     Montly Average
255 1993-07-31  14.490000     Montly Average
256 1993-06-30  15.400000     Montly Average
257 1993-05-31  16.070000     Montly Average
258 1993-04-30  16.430000     Montly Average
259 1993-03-31  16.440000     Montly Average
260 1993-02-28  16.160000     Montly Average
261 1993-01-31  15.300000     Montly Average
262 1992-12-31  16.220000     Montly Average
263 1992-11-30  17.210000     Montly Average
264 1992-10-31  18.160000     Montly Average
265 1992-09-30  18.360000     Montly Average
266 1992-08-31  17.780000     Montly Average
267 1992-07-31  18.440000     Montly Average
268 1992-06-30  18.980000     Montly Average
269 1992-05-31  17.570000     Montly Average
270 1992-04-30  16.670000     Montly Average
271 1992-03-31  15.560000     Montly Average
272 1992-02-29  15.460000     Montly Average
273 1992-01-31  15.250000     Montly Average
274 1991-12-31  15.110000     Montly Average
275 1991-11-30  17.760000     Montly Average
276 1991-10-31  19.120000     Montly Average
277 1991-09-30  17.500000     Montly Average
278 1991-08-31  16.470000     Montly Average
279 1991-07-31  16.130000     Montly Average
280 1991-06-30  15.030000     Montly Average
281 1991-05-31  15.770000     Montly Average
282 1991-04-30  15.550000     Montly Average
283 1991-03-31  15.650000     Montly Average
284 1991-02-28  15.510000     Montly Average
285 1991-01-31  19.680000     Montly Average
286 1990-12-31  24.180000     Montly Average
287 1990-11-30  28.980000     Montly Average
288 1990-10-31  32.340000     Montly Average
289 1990-09-30  32.030000     Montly Average
290 1990-08-31  25.060000     Montly Average
291 1990-07-31  14.880000     Montly Average
292 1990-06-30  13.050000     Montly Average
293 1990-05-31  14.030000     Montly Average
294 1990-04-30  14.050000     Montly Average
295 1990-03-31  15.590000     Montly Average
296 1990-02-28  17.000000     Montly Average
297 1990-01-31  17.570000     Montly Average
298 1989-12-31  17.120000     Montly Average
299 1989-11-30  16.040000     Montly Average
300 1989-10-31  16.140000     Montly Average
301 1989-09-30  15.710000     Montly Average
302 1989-08-31  14.910000     Montly Average
303 1989-07-31  15.540000     Montly Average
304 1989-06-30  15.600000     Montly Average
305 1989-05-31  15.860000     Montly Average
306 1989-04-30  17.110000     Montly Average
307 1989-03-31  16.130000     Montly Average
308 1989-02-28  14.840000     Montly Average
309 1989-01-31  14.370000     Montly Average
310 1988-12-31  12.570000     Montly Average
311 1988-11-30  10.550000     Montly Average
312 1988-10-31  10.630000     Montly Average
313 1988-09-30  11.770000     Montly Average
314 1988-08-31  13.190000     Montly Average
315 1988-07-31  12.980000     Montly Average
316 1988-06-30  14.410000     Montly Average
317 1988-05-31  15.260000     Montly Average
318 1988-04-30  14.730000     Montly Average
319 1988-03-31  13.590000     Montly Average
320 1988-02-29  15.200000     Montly Average
321 1988-01-31  15.440000     Montly Average
322 1987-12-31  15.610000     Montly Average
323 1987-11-30  16.740000     Montly Average
324 1987-10-31  17.170000     Montly Average
325 1987-09-30  17.010000     Montly Average
326 1987-08-31  17.300000     Montly Average
327 1987-07-31  17.670000     Montly Average
328 1987-06-30  17.200000     Montly Average
329 1987-05-31  17.040000     Montly Average
330 1987-04-30  17.040000     Montly Average
331 1987-03-31  16.930000     Montly Average
332 1987-02-28  16.740000     Montly Average
333 1987-01-31  17.120000     Montly Average
334 1986-12-31  14.500000     Montly Average
335 1986-11-30  13.700000     Montly Average
336 1986-10-31  13.280000     Montly Average
337 1986-09-30  12.920000     Montly Average
338 1986-08-31  11.710000     Montly Average
339 1986-07-31   8.500000     Montly Average
340 1986-06-30  10.380000     Montly Average
341 1986-05-31  11.020000     Montly Average
342 1986-04-30  10.330000     Montly Average
343 1986-03-31  11.970000     Montly Average
344 1986-02-28  16.430000     Montly Average
345 1986-01-31  21.930000     Montly Average
346 1985-12-31  26.390000     Montly Average
347 1985-11-30  26.920000     Montly Average
348 1985-10-31  26.740000     Montly Average
349 1985-09-30  26.580000     Montly Average
350 1985-08-31  26.290000     Montly Average
351 1985-07-31  25.730000     Montly Average
352 1985-06-30  25.430000     Montly Average
353 1985-05-31  25.680000     Montly Average
354 1985-04-30  26.710000     Montly Average
355 1985-03-31  27.130000     Montly Average
356 1985-02-28  27.200000     Montly Average
357 1985-01-31  27.300000     Montly Average
358 1984-12-31  26.720000     Montly Average
359 1984-11-30  27.100000     Montly Average
360 1984-10-31  27.260000     Montly Average
361 1984-09-30  27.430000     Montly Average
362 1984-08-31  27.140000     Montly Average
363 1984-07-31  27.260000     Montly Average
364 1984-06-30  28.000000     Montly Average
365 1984-05-31  28.010000     Montly Average
366 1984-04-30  27.980000     Montly Average
367 1984-03-31  27.830000     Montly Average
368 1984-02-29  27.630000     Montly Average
369 1984-01-31  27.750000     Montly Average
370 1983-12-31  27.540000     Montly Average
371 1983-11-30  27.810000     Montly Average
372 1983-10-31  28.130000     Montly Average
373 1983-09-30  28.390000     Montly Average
374 1983-08-31  28.610000     Montly Average
375 1983-07-31  28.620000     Montly Average
376 1983-06-30  28.160000     Montly Average
377 1983-05-31  28.500000     Montly Average
378 1983-04-30  28.700000     Montly Average
379 1983-03-31  28.100000     Montly Average
380 1983-02-28  29.000000     Montly Average
381 1983-01-31  30.050000     Montly Average
382 1982-12-31  30.100000     Montly Average
383 1982-11-30  31.750000     Montly Average
384 1982-10-31  33.400000     Montly Average
385 1982-09-30  33.050000     Montly Average
386 1982-08-31  31.200000     Montly Average
387 1982-07-31  31.700000     Montly Average
388 1982-06-30  32.650000     Montly Average
389 1982-05-31  33.350000     Montly Average
390 1982-04-30  30.880000     Montly Average
391 1982-03-31  28.600000     Montly Average
392 1982-02-28  30.400000     Montly Average
393 1982-01-31  34.000000     Montly Average
394 1981-12-31  34.120000     Montly Average
395 1981-11-30  34.240000     Montly Average
396 1981-10-31  32.680000     Montly Average
397 1981-09-30  32.060000     Montly Average
398 1981-08-31  32.170000     Montly Average
399 1981-07-31  31.960000     Montly Average
400 1981-06-30  32.170000     Montly Average
401 1981-05-31  33.380000     Montly Average
402 1981-04-30  35.550000     Montly Average
403 1981-03-31  36.850000     Montly Average
404 1981-02-28  37.100000     Montly Average
405 1981-01-31  39.250000     Montly Average
406 1980-12-31  39.350000     Montly Average
407 1980-11-30  39.750000     Montly Average
408 1980-10-31  36.800000     Montly Average
409 1980-09-30  32.250000     Montly Average
410 1980-08-31  32.300000     Montly Average
411 1980-07-31  33.350000     Montly Average
412 1980-06-30  36.000000     Montly Average
413 1980-05-31  35.600000     Montly Average
414 1980-04-30  35.000000     Montly Average
415 1980-03-31  35.750000     Montly Average
416 1980-02-29  36.000000     Montly Average
417 1980-01-31  38.000000     Montly Average
418 1980-01-01  35.845833     Yearly Average
419 1981-01-01  34.294167     Yearly Average
420 1982-01-01  31.756667     Yearly Average
421 1983-01-01  28.467500     Yearly Average
422 1984-01-01  27.509167     Yearly Average
423 1985-01-01  26.508333     Yearly Average
424 1986-01-01  13.055833     Yearly Average
425 1987-01-01  16.964167     Yearly Average
426 1988-01-01  13.360000     Yearly Average
427 1989-01-01  15.780833     Yearly Average
428 1990-01-01  20.730000     Yearly Average
429 1991-01-01  16.606667     Yearly Average
430 1992-01-01  17.138333     Yearly Average
431 1993-01-01  14.905833     Yearly Average
432 1994-01-01  14.831667     Yearly Average
433 1995-01-01  16.127500     Yearly Average
434 1996-01-01  18.536667     Yearly Average
435 1997-01-01  18.101667     Yearly Average
436 1998-01-01  12.090000     Yearly Average
437 1999-01-01  17.075833     Yearly Average
438 2000-01-01  26.085000     Yearly Average
439 2001-01-01  22.710000     Yearly Average
440 2002-01-01  23.734167     Yearly Average
441 2003-01-01  26.733333     Yearly Average
442 2004-01-01  33.455833     Yearly Average
443 2005-01-01  49.201667     Yearly Average
444 2006-01-01  61.431667     Yearly Average
445 2007-01-01  68.368333     Yearly Average
446 2008-01-01  93.776667     Yearly Average
447 2009-01-01  61.756667     Yearly Average
448 2010-01-01  78.057500     Yearly Average
449 2011-01-01 106.025833     Yearly Average
450 2012-01-01 108.921667     Yearly Average
451 2013-01-01 105.427500     Yearly Average
452 2014-01-01 104.014444     Yearly Average
453 1980-01-31   3.650447 Standard Deviation
454 1984-12-31   3.650447 Standard Deviation
455 1985-01-31   5.256374 Standard Deviation
456 1989-12-31   5.256374 Standard Deviation
457 1990-01-31   4.027496 Standard Deviation
458 1994-12-31   4.027496 Standard Deviation
459 1995-01-31   3.313954 Standard Deviation
460 1999-12-31   3.313954 Standard Deviation
461 2000-01-31   4.619182 Standard Deviation
462 2004-12-31   4.619182 Standard Deviation
463 2005-01-31  20.926305 Standard Deviation
464 2009-12-31  20.926305 Standard Deviation
465 2010-01-31  12.778173 Standard Deviation
466 2014-09-30  12.778173 Standard Deviation
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this??

[image]

```
df.labels <- aggregate(Date~Value,
                       data.final[data.final$Type=="Standard Deviation",],
                       mean)
ggplot(data.final, aes(x=Date, y=Value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=Type)) +
  geom_text(data=df.labels,aes(y=Value+5, label=round(Value,2)),size=3) + 
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("Price (2013 U.S. Dollars)")
```